# All necessary opacity settings for all browsers?

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, safari, opacity

I often use opacity in my codes like this:

```
opacity:0;
filter: alpha(opacity=0);
-moz-opacity:0;
-khtml-opacity:0;
```

To be honest, I don't know if these four are enough to let the opacity work on every browser. Or is already enough to only use opacity:x;`enter code here` to let it work everywhere? Which are ones that I should definitely use?

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=opacity

Comment: Do u need to support ie8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opacity is supported in [all browsers even IE](http://caniuse.com/#search=opacity). If you want to check if your CSS is supported on any browser just visit [CanIuse](http://caniuse.com).